# Listview with Dynamic Controls - Dynamic controls disappear after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-controls, dynamic-controls

I have a listview that loads dynamic controls from xml/xslt

```
 <asp:ListView ID="DynamicFields" runat="server"
          DataSourceID="CustomFields" 
          OnItemDataBound="DynamicFields_ItemDataBound"                                                                              
          GroupItemCount="2" ItemPlaceholderID="itemsGroup" 
          GroupPlaceholderID="itemsGroup">
      <LayoutTemplate>
         <table width="470" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
             <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemsGroup" runat="server" />
         </table>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <GroupTemplate>
         <tr>
             <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemsGroup"></asp:PlaceHolder>
         </tr>
      </GroupTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
           <custom:CustomField ID="Field" runat="server" 
              FieldIndex='<%# Eval("index") %>' /> 
      </ItemTemplate>  
      <AlternatingItemTemplate>
           <custom:CustomField ID="Field" runat="server" 
              FieldIndex='<%# Eval("index") %>' />
      </AlternatingItemTemplate>        
</asp:ListView>
```

And in my page codebehind I'm binding user control properties and calling bind method that loads xml and creates controls

```
protected void DynamicFields_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            ucCustomField uc = (ucCustomField)e.Item.FindControl("Field");
            uc.FileName = FORM_PATH;
            uc.FormName = FORM_NAME;
            uc.LoadXMLFile(); //binding xml content here
        }
    }
```

I add this listview to an existing form which has static controls and save button. When I click button it causes validation and shows me validation summary popup messages[expected] and all my dynamic controls in listview disappear after i click ok in popup.
How can I keep these controls visible and also any values that may have been entered after postback?

Comment: Do you have a Validation Event..? if so can you paste that code also what is the exact error that it's returning..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by calling `DynamicFields.DataBind()` when `Page.IsPostback` is true

Answer (score 0):

> And in my page codebehind i'm binding user control properties and calling bind method that loads xml and creates controls

Can you tell where are you calling the Bind/Databind method. Putting that in pageload will i guess solve the issue. The post back will remove anything that has been dynamically added to the page.

Regards,
SJ

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are not inside of a Header not sure if this will help or not but try the following

```
if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
    || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
}
```

Comment: I'm using Listview and ListviewItemType has dataitem only.